# Problems on creation of executable file from python with Nuitka

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, nuitka

I am trying to create an `exe file` from a python file that it will be executable to other PCs. I came across Nuitka.I use Python 2.7.11 Anaconda 2.3.0 (32 bit) on Windows 8.1 64 bit. Because of my work specs i can't update my Python version!!! I have download nuitka 0.5.19 for python 2.7. At first i used the simple line `nuitka --exe python.py` and i get an executable (with some warnings) that runs only in PCs that had install Python (obvious!). Then i used `nuitka --standalone python.py` in order to include the libruries and i got a major list of warnings and a final flag for Memory Error. Hear are the Warnings:

```
C:\exefile>nuitka --standalone hybrid_SSP2exe.py
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:82: Cannot find 'wx' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:91: Cannot find 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:98: Cannot find 'gi.repository' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:101: Cannot find 'gobject' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\hatch.py:9: Cannot find 'matplotlib.externals.six.moves' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\__init__.py:7: Cannot find 'mklfft.fftpack' in package 'numpy.fft' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\suite.py:22: Cannot find 'clr' in package 'nose' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\suite.py:24: Cannot find 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions' in package 'nose' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\skip.py:22: Cannot find 'unittest2.case' in package 'nose.plugins' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nose\plugins\manager.py:378: Cannot find 'pkg_resources' in package 'nose.plugins' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\eventloops.py:93: Cannot find 'wx' in package 'IPython.kernel.zmq' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py:250: Cannot find '_imaging_gif' in package 'PIL' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cffi\ffiplatform.py:22: Cannot find 'setuptools' in package 'cffi' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cffi\recompiler.py:1229: Cannot find 'testing.udir' in package 'cffi' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\gui\gtk3embed.py:17: Cannot find 'gi.repository' in package 'IPython.kernel.zmq.gui' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\gui\gtkembed.py:17: Cannot find 'gobject' in package 'IPython.kernel.zmq.gui' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\gui\gtkembed.py:18: Cannot find 'gtk' in package 'IPython.kernel.zmq.gui' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\guisupport.py:77: Cannot find 'wx' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\appnope\__init__.py:3: Cannot find 'appnope' in package 'IPython.external.appnope' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:Use --plugin-enable=qt-plugins for: Inclusion of Qt plugins.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt_loaders.py:208: Cannot find 'PyQt5' in package 'IPython.external' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt_loaders.py:229: Cannot find 'PySide' in package 'IPython.external' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\path.py:122: Cannot find 'pkg_resources' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\ssh\tunnel.py:35: Cannot find 'pexpect' in package 'zmq.ssh' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\ssh\forward.py:33: Cannot find 'socketserver' in package 'zmq.ssh' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ecdsa\numbertheory.py:15: Cannot find 'six.moves' in package 'ecdsa' 1 package level up.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ssh_gss.py:68: Cannot find 'gssapi' in package 'paramiko' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\localinterfaces.py:144: Cannot find 'netifaces' in package 'IPython.utils' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py:29: Cannot find 'pkg_resources' in package 'pytz' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tzwin.py:5: Cannot find 'six.moves' in package 'dateutil' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py:18: Cannot find 'matplotlib.externals.six.moves.urllib.request' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\pickleutil.py:58: Cannot find 'dill' in package 'IPython.utils' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\pickleutil.py:81: Cannot find 'cloud.serialization' in package 'IPython.utils' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\pexpect\__init__.py:2: Cannot find 'pexpect' in package 'IPython.external.pexpect' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_cli.py:15: Cannot find 'clr' in package 'IPython.utils' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_cli.py:16: Cannot find 'System' in package 'IPython.utils' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py:46: Cannot find 'pydb' in package 'IPython.core' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py:229: Cannot find 'pydb.fns' in package 'IPython.core' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhook.py:406: Cannot find 'gtk' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhook.py:471: Cannot find 'OpenGL.GLUT' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhook.py:504: Cannot find 'glut_support' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhookgtk3.py:20: Cannot find 'gi.repository' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhookpyglet.py:27: Cannot find 'pyglet' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhookglut.py:38: Cannot find 'OpenGL.platform' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\inputhookgtk.py:20: Cannot find 'gobject' in package 'IPython.lib' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\common.py:127: Cannot find 'startup' in package 'pyreadline.keysyms' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\ironpython_keysyms.py:10: Cannot find 'System' in package 'pyreadline.keysyms' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\clipboard\ironpython_clipboard.py:9: Cannot find 'clr' in package 'pyreadline.clipboard' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\clipboard\ironpython_clipboard.py:11: Cannot find 'System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard' in package 'pyreadline.clipboard' as absolute
import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\ansi.py:177: Cannot find 'console' in package 'pyreadline.console' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\ironpython_console.py:29: Cannot find 'clr' in package 'pyreadline.console' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\ironpython_console.py:31: Cannot find 'IronPythonConsole' in package 'pyreadline.console' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\ironpython_console.py:37: Cannot find 'System' in package 'pyreadline.console' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py:31: Cannot find 'System' in package 'pyreadline' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py:29: Cannot find 'urllib3' in package 'requests.packages' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py:35: Cannot find 'chardet' in package 'requests.packages' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\response.py:2: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3' 2 package levels up.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py:13: Cannot find 'packages.six.moves' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3' 1 package level up.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py:54: Cannot find 'http.cookies' in package 'requests' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py:125: Cannot find '_speedups' in package 'simplejson' 1 package level up.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py:6: Cannot find 'simplejson._speedups' in package 'simplejson' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:49: Cannot find 'ndg.httpsclient.ssl_peer_verification' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3
.contrib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py:50: Cannot find 'ndg.httpsclient.subj_alt_name' in package 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib
' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py:161: Cannot find 'rfc3987' in package 'jsonschema' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py:173: Cannot find 'strict_rfc3339' in package 'jsonschema' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py:176: Cannot find 'isodate' in package 'jsonschema' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\_format.py:215: Cannot find 'webcolors' in package 'jsonschema' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\minitornado\platform\auto.py:39: Cannot find 'monotime' in package 'zmq.eventloop.minitornado.platform' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\auto.py:44: Cannot find 'monotime' in package 'tornado.platform' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py:37: Cannot find 'concurrent' in package 'tornado' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\context.py:84: Cannot find 'pyczmq' in package 'zmq.sugar' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py:24: Cannot find 'pysqlite2' in package 'IPython.core' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\simplegeneric\__init__.py:2: Cannot find 'simplegeneric' in package 'IPython.external.simplegeneric' as relative or absolut
e import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\testing\iptestcontroller.py:639: Cannot find 'coverage' in package 'IPython.testing' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\testing\iptestcontroller.py:652: Cannot find 'coverage.html' in package 'IPython.testing' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:1016: Cannot find 'pydb' in package 'IPython.core' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py:22: Cannot find 'matplotlib.externals.six.moves.urllib.parse' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py:3418: Cannot find 'mpl_toolkits.natgrid' in package 'matplotlib' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tri\triinterpolate.py:8: Cannot find 'matplotlib.externals.six.moves' in package 'matplotlib.tri' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:5: Cannot find 'matplotlib.externals.six.moves' in package 'matplotlib.axes' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_svg.py:5: Cannot find 'matplotlib.externals.six.moves' in package 'matplotlib.backends' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py:423: Cannot find 'concurrent.futures' in package 'tornado' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py:96: Cannot find 'singledispatch' in package 'tornado' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\httputil.py:41: Cannot find 'http.cookies' in package 'tornado' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cycler.py:6: Cannot find 'six.moves' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py:21: Cannot find 'Image' in package 'scipy.misc' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\pilutil.py:22: Cannot find 'ImageFilter' in package 'scipy.misc' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\dsolve\linsolve.py:14: Cannot find 'scikits.umfpack' in package 'scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\npy_pkg_config.py:10: Cannot find 'configparser' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2000: Cannot find 'Numeric' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2005: Cannot find 'numarray' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\diagnose.py:51: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\diagnose.py:91: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils.command.build_flib' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\diagnose.py:113: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\diagnose.py:136: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils.command.cpuinfo' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\diagnose.py:142: Cannot find 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py:18: Cannot find 'Pyrex.Compiler.Main' in package 'numpy.distutils.command' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\__version__.py:6: Cannot find '__svn_version__' in package 'numpy.f2py' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py:8: Cannot find 'setuptools' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py:10: Cannot find 'setuptools.command' in package 'numpy.distutils' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py:3: Cannot find 'setuptools.command.egg_info' in package 'numpy.distutils.command' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\develop.py:8: Cannot find 'setuptools.command.develop' in package 'numpy.distutils.command' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\bdist_rpm.py:6: Cannot find 'setuptools.command.bdist_rpm' in package 'numpy.distutils.command' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\install.py:5: Cannot find 'setuptools.command.install' in package 'numpy.distutils.command' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\sdist.py:5: Cannot find 'setuptools.command.sdist' in package 'numpy.distutils.command' as absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:Use --plugin-enable=pylint-warnings for: Understand PyLint/PyDev annotations for warnings.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\testing.py:268: Cannot find 'py.path' in package 'pandas.util' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\testing.py:506: Cannot find 'pudb' in package 'pandas.util' as relative or absolute import.
Nuitka:WARNING:C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numexpr\tests\test_numexpr.py:863: Cannot find 'pkg_resources' in package 'numexpr.tests' as absolute import.
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:361:
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:361:
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:359:
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:359:
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:68:
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:68:
Problem with statement at C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py:68:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\Scripts\nuitka", line 193, in <module>
    MainControl.main()
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nuitka\MainControl.py", line 695, in main
    filename = filename
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nuitka\MainControl.py", line 100, in createNodeTree
    Optimization.optimize()
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nuitka\optimizations\Optimization.py", line 320, in optimize
    changed = optimizePythonModule(current_module)
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nuitka\optimizations\Optimization.py", line 99, in optimizePythonModule
    info("Interrupted while working on '%s'." % module)
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1621, in info
    root.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1159, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1277, in _log
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1251, in makeRecord
    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
  File "C:\Users\ennoisis\Anaconda\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.pathname = pathname
MemoryError
```

I red requirments for Nuitka and i saw that i haven't had MinGW. I had manage to install with a lot of effort from SourceForge, because minwg installer had a bug. I got the mingw32 version (match with my python version). The gcc version that i have after the installation is:

```
C:\exefile>gcc --version
gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

After that i tried again `nuitka --exe python.py` and i does not work also. I am newbie at python but i am a quick learner and i don't know C++. 
Just for the record, the python file returns numbers and figures. Can anyone help me and guide me. Thanks in advance!!!

Kind regards,
Thanasis

Comment: Identical issue (years later).  Did you resolve?  I use anaconda too that could be the issue

Comment: I get: nuitka --exe 123.py --recurse-none
Error, cannot find "gendef.exe" which is required though.

Comment: You may want to try `mingw_w64`. It is not for 64-bit windows but also for 32-bit windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your "cannot find x in package y" errors may be solved by adding

```
export LDFLAGS="-rdynamic"
```

prior to

```
nuitka --standalone hybrid_SSP2exe.py
```